# Search for the code/name then display to the user inside input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

I have Master table in my system accessed by administrator who can add/edit/delete records in that table. These records are usually codes with description. Users simply should choose the code/name and that will be populated in the text input field. Recently I got back some feed back on how this work and they want to change it. I'm just trying to make the right decision since requested change in my opinion can cause some issues. Here is example:

```js
var myJSON = {
  positions: [{
      name: "Programmer",
      code: 135
    },
    {
      name: "Developer",
      code: 170
    },
    {
      name: "Secretary",
      code: 35
    },
    {
      name: "Supervisor",
      code: 45
    }
  ]
}

$('.modal-master').on('keyup', showMasterModal);
$('.modal-master').on('click', showMasterModal);

function showMasterModal(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elementID = e.target.id,
    searchVal = $.trim($(this).val()),
    fldID = elementID === "frm_position1" ? 'frm_position1' : 'frm_position2';

  if ((fldID === "frm_position1" && searchVal.length >= 1) || fldID === "frm_position2") {
    var jsonData = myJSON.positions,
      modalTbl = "<table id='masterRecords' class='table table-hover stripe'><thead><tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    for (key in jsonData) {
      modalTbl += "<tr><td>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].code) + "</td>";
      modalTbl += "<td>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].name) + "</td>";
      modalTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm choose-masterItem'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up'></span></button></td></tr>";

    }

    modalTbl += "</tbody></table>";
    $('#master_modalTbl').empty().append(modalTbl);
    buildDataTable('masterRecords', [2], 5);
    $('#masterModal').modal('show');

    $('#masterRecords').on('click', ':button.choose-masterItem', function() {
      var itemCode = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        itemName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
      $('#' + fldID).val(itemCode).attr('title', '(' + itemCode + ') ' + itemName);
      $('#masterModal').modal('hide');
    });
  }
};

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<!--- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** --->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="position1"><span class="label label-info">Position 1:</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control modal-master" name="frm_position1" id="frm_position1" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter at least one letters of Position name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="position2"><span class="label label-info">Position 2:</span></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_position2" id="frm_position2" maxlength="50" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary modal-master" id="btn_pos">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="masterModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Master</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body table-responsive" id="master_modalTbl">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In example above you can see both ways to get the Position name & code. My original solution was one with the button. Users would click on the plus sign button and see all positions. Then they can search through data table or switch pages. This way all records will be available and they can search through them. Input field is set to read only and that will prevent users entering by mistake some corrupter or incomplete data. First solution where they can type at least one letter and then search for is what they requested. I'm opposed tot hat solution since they can partially enter the name or code then not select one from the pop up modal, that will be incorrect data. Also I'm still debating should I save code and name in the input field or maybe just name and keep code in title attribute or other way around? Is there any standard for this kind of situation in web development? I'm looking for convenient and clean solution where users would be satisfied as well.

Comment: Hi there, Based on my knowledge, Your first approach seems to be the proper approach where you would have '+' button on both input fields when a user clicks, it shows all the positions and this is where the user can search and chose the option and the correct value will be passed to the input after selection - and not the other way around. Other way around will be not error prone. If you were to think this other way, it is more like a drop down list with search in new modal and limiting user input interference. You're going in right direction with first approach.

Comment: @PKA So you recommend button with plus sign and read only input field?

Comment: Yes, on both fields. Because a user can search 'y' in the field and when the results are displayed, it will limited and you have to show all results as well in the modal. It's kinda like you will have these functionality twice - 1) in input search 2) in modal search. I would just have two plus icons and that pops modal, user can search and select the desired result. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: @PKA Absolutely make sense to me and that was the original solution, now I have to convince old fashion customers why this is better option. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yea, I can understand! what I would propose is the functionality is repeated twice on input and on search window and from UI perspective, it could really confuse the user if they don't see the reset buttons unless they all are pro users.

You can mention that the one letter search result functionality that they want is in search window, where a user can see all the results initially and search for what they want. OR Unless they want something like google search where you type a letter... and you get all results down below.